# Multiple objects serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am making a ToDoList-Console app that needs serialisation of multiple objects.
There are 2 task classes:

- Simple task
- Complex task

I need a method that serialises and desirealize these tasks, something like `WriteAndReadComplexTask`, for both the classes that does not rewrite the whole `tasks.json` file, but adds it up. This is what I am aiming for as an end result:

```
[
 {
    "SimpleTask": "do the dishes"
 }
 {
    "ComplexTask": "buy groceries"
      { "subtask": "bananas",
        "subtask": "apples"}
 }
 {
    "simple task": "do some coding"
 }
]
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON.  Each property name should be surrounded by double quotes, as well as each text value.

Comment: thanks @jason.kaisersmith , I am new to json so I didnt knew

Comment: To be blunt, if you decide on using a text file for your data storage then yes, you **can** write code to handle partial rewrites but it's going to be **very hard** to do. If you need to be able to do random access updates to your storage, don't use JSON or other text file formats, use a database like sqlite.

Comment: Do you need to use text based serialization? I know protobuf .net can use `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` to append arbitrary number of messages to a stream.

Comment: i don't need to, but since im a beginner and i did not understand anything you said I think i should stick to the easier stuff. Sorry @JonasH

Comment: @Rarowcun There are couple of online tools, like [Json Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) which can help you to validate your json file and fix it based on the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't too hard to do. But I think you are approaching the problem from a different angle I suggest you try getting this to work with just 1 class which contains all fields already and using 1 todoitem task. This saves time and complex logic because otherwise you might need to convert items from simple tasks to complex tasks in the future.

1. First of all, your JSON is still not correct. you are missing comma's after each object.
2. I suggest changing your JSON to the following:

```json
[
     {
        "name": "SimpleTask"
        "description": "do the dishes"
     },
     {
        "name": "Simple task",
        "description": "buy groceries",
         "subtasks":[ 
             {"name": "Simple task",
        "description": "buy groceries"},{.... repeat another item}]
     },
     {
         ..another item here 
     }
]
```

3. Create a new class where which looks like the object in your JSON like this:

```
public class TodoItem 
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string description {get;set;}
    public List<TodoItem> subtasks {get;set;}
}
```

4. Now in your code load the file and use the following to load to C#

```
var todoitems = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<TodoItem>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: okay so, after much trial and error i got it working, kind of. Im a beginner so correct me if im wrong but i think the class `ToDoItem` needs a `Public Override string ToString()`, so when I deserialise them i can print out strings. Also, how would you go about the subtasks list? i have troubles printing them out. I tried implementing `Strin.Join` directly into the return statement of `ToString()`. It manages to serialise and deserialise it but it cannot print it with a `foreach` loop

Comment: @Rarowcun You don't need the override but it's one way of doing things, no problem. You could also create a new function which allows a ToDoItem and print inside the function. You can Print it for example with 
`Console.Writeline($"name: {ToDoItem.name} description: {ToDoItem.description}")` and now you can add an `foreach(var subtask in ToDoItem.subtasks)
{ 
   ToDoItem.ToString()
}`